# import Meteor and Mongo into an npm package

Tags: meteor, npm

Like you can use

`import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';`

and

`import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';`

within a meteor project.

I'm wondering If there is anyway to add this functionality to an NPM package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use MongoDB in an NPM project you're better off using something like [the NPM mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) package.

Meteor is working on migrating it's core to NPM, but for the time being sometimes you have to [Depend on Atmosphere packages](https://guide.meteor.com/atmosphere-vs-npm.html):

> Atmosphere packages are packages written specifically for Meteor and have several advantages over npm when used with Meteor. In particular, Atmosphere packages can:
>
> - Depend on core Meteor packages, such as ddp and blaze
> - ...

**Other Sources**

- [With the upgrade, Meteor 1.3 offers better integration and support for JavaScript specs](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3048806/javascript/meteor-javascript-framework-moves-to-npm.html)

Comment: Thank you! So effectively I would have to wrap my NPM package in a Atmostphere package?
I've got another question if I use MongoDB within NPM how would I connect to the meteor mongo database? where do I find the connection string?